# Data transfer from tiny MCE in HTML to php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I am sending data from tinymce in HTML to PHP, the data can be received but its coming as HTML code…how to resolve it and get the data back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE is an HTML editor.  Accept the data from TinyMCE (sanitize it) and store it in the database.  When you display it in the page, it will be as entered by the user.

If you want to remove all the HTML tags, you can use **strip_tags**.